# Flex responsive columns of images and text without media queries

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a flex puzzle: what I'm trying to do is use flex for responsive columns, where the right hand column will move below the row as the viewport narrows without using a media query. This works with the images; but I can't get the text to go under the image - it floats to the right, even if in its own `<div>` under the image. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this with media queries?

https://jsfiddle.net/9n8pdbq5/

HTML

```
<div class="issues-columns">

<div class="issue-col">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
Text text text
</div>

<div class="issue-col">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
Text text text
</div>

<div class="issue-col">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
Text text text
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.issues-columns {
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-start;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.issue-col {
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 0;
flex-basis: 33.3333%;
flex-basis: 300px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `flex-direction` to `column` on your parent element. Then set both children `img` and `text` to `display: inline-flex`.

```css
.issues-columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.issue-col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="issues-columns">

  <div class="issue-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200"/>
    <span>Text text text</span>
  </div>

  <div class="issue-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200"/>

    <span>Text text text</span>
  </div>

  <div class="issue-col">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200"/>

    <span>Text text text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Coming to what you're 'doing wrong', HTML reads anything in the `div` element from left to right (like it reads any text content) as a whole content. To bring your text down you shall explicitly tell that both `text` and `image` are two child elements with their own right and parent shall treat them separately.

Comment: Thanks! This works; I changed the span to a div with the same class inline-flex. One more detail: justify-content: flex-start is supposed to have all issue-col start on the left, but these are all centered; how would I have them all aligned left?

Comment: Assign `align-items: flex-start;` on `.issue-col` then you can perhaps remove `justify-content`  you can read more about the actual behaviour of these properties here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to wrap-up the image and text into one more `div`
Now doing this you will get the output as **DIV 1** 
The text will be just after the image now this is because as `<img />` is an `inline-element`

The other two `div's` have the text under the image as I have wrapped the text in `<h2>`. The text is under the image as `<h2>` is a `block-element`.

Read More [Inline Vs Block Elements](https://codeburst.io/block-level-and-inline-elements-the-difference-between-div-and-span-2f8502c1f95b)

```css
.issues-columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.issue-col {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 33.3333%;
  flex-basis: 300px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="issues-columns">
 <!-- DIV 1 -->
  <div class="issue-col">
    <div>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" /> Text text text
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="issue-col">
    <div>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
      <h2>Text text text </h2>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="issue-col">
    <div>
      <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" />
      <h2>Text text text </h2>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used a modified version of adding another div in my comments to RegarBoy.